# Selecting one record using spring and hibernate with javax.persistence.Query

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am using spring boot project with hibernate,
How to query using *javax.persistence.Query*

```
@Override
public List<Bank> balance(String account_name) {
    Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT balance from bank WHERE account_name=:account_name", Bank.class);
    query.setParameter("account_name", account_name);
    if (query.getResultList().size() == 1) {
        return query.getResultList();
    }

    return null;

}
```

This is giving error

> "message": "could not execute query; SQL [SELECT balance from bank];
>   nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could
>   not execute query"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated your code a little bit, try it please and below there is some explanation:

```
@Override
public List<Bank> balance(String account_name) {
  Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("select * from <TABLE_NAME> where <COLUMN_NAME> = ?", Bank.class);
  query.setParameter(1, account_name); // here we set value for param (it's "?" in the SQL)
  query.setMaxResults(1); // this is used to limit the result list

  // you should probably remove this
  /* if (query.getResultList().size() == 1 ) {
    return query.getResultList();
  }*/

  return query.getResultList();
}
```

First, the native SQL query: you need to use table name and columns name there, so these `<TABLE_NAME>`, `<COLUMN_NAME>` have to be replaced with your table name and column name (*not entity name or entity's field name !*).

Second, if you want to get only one record it's better to use `query.setMaxResults(1)`; you can also change its argument - to retrieve as many records as you need.

If you know that you always need only 1 record maybe it makes sense to change your method a little. Try something like this code:

```
@Override
public Bank balance(String account_name) {
  Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("select * from <TABLE_NAME> where <COLUMN_NAME> = ?", Bank.class);

  query.setParameter(1, account_name);
  query.setMaxResults(1);

  return (Bank)query.getSingleResult();
}
```

In this case you can use `getSingleResult()` instead of `getResultList()`.

In general, it is not a good practice to return `null` if your method returns a list of smth. like this `public List<Bank> balance(String account_name)`. It's better to return an empty list for instance.

Hope this makes some sense :)

Happy hacking!